# zgrep on multiple input variables issue

Tags: bash, shell, grep, zgrep

I have an issue using `zgrep`. I want to look for a XML file based on an `ID` and a certain `Date` given by the user.
Each XML file contains an ID and a date in it. The program should acknowledge that these files may have the same ID but a different Date. I tried to use zgrep but I don't know how to look for two different variables and my code doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
echo "Introduce ID: "
read -r InputCode
echo "Set a specific Date [ DD-MM-YYYY ]: "
read -r Date

#Search patterns in every zip folder
find . -print0 | xargs -0 zgrep -l $InputCode && $Date
```

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot grep both ID and Date with a single grep command if they are not on the same line. 
Try this:

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 zgrep -lZ -e "$InputCode" | xargs -0 zgrep -l -e "$Date"
```

Comment: It works! thank you so much. It can find the first file of each zip folder but not the other files. you think might be a bug?

Comment: It sees works fine on my machine. But there are certain bugs about zgrep on some distributions.

Comment: Thank you for helping me guys